# Which dialect uses "けえ" instead of "から"?

Tags: words, slang, dialects

In Yakuza 6, a guy called Nagumo speaks with a dialect. Just an example of one line from him is

"今度こそ白黒つけちゃるけえの"

which, in regular japanese, I'm assuming is

"今度こそ白黒つけてやるからな"

Anyways, he keeps using "けえ" at the end of sentences (I'm assuming it's a dialect version of "から"). What region is this dialect from? I have a feeling it's a Kyuushuu dialect, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: It is a common expression in both 九州、四国、and 中国地方.  With that said, I cant produce an easy to read reliable source other than wikipages for the 3 dialects.  I hope someone else can provide a reliable source.

Comment: Fwiw, I think Hiroshima might be the most likely suspect, as the scene takes place in a fictional city in Hiroshima Prefecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the following, it is a dialect of 中国地方. Personally, in fictions, it is mostly 広島 or 岡山 that is represented by the use of けえ for reason. In Kyushu, it is generally けん rather than けえ.

- [日本語の方言の比較表](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E3%81%AE%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83%E8%A1%A8#)

(You can see "理由" in 近畿から中国にかけて（山陽道）/ 近畿から中国にかけて（山陰道）)